# Why is the image being captured returning null?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bitmap, onactivityresult

I have this application where once the user takes a photo using the camera app, it will automatically set the `ImageView` in the application to that captured image. I keep getting this error and it's causing my application to crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.company.example/com.company.example.Camera}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The error occurs here, specifically the `foodBitmap` line:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val foodBitmap = Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(data)!!.extras)!!["data"] as Bitmap
    food_image.setImageBitmap(foodBitmap)
}
```

These are the two functions I'm using to capture the image. I have all the permissions set up properly:

```
private fun openCamera() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            val photoFile: File? = try {
                createImageFile()
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                null
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            photoFile?.also {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(applicationContext),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile
                )
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return File.createTempFile(
        "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
        ".jpg", /* suffix */
        storageDir /* directory */
    ).apply {
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is `data` in `onActivityResult` null?